# Custom columnAutoresizingStyle with NSTableView

Tags: nstableview, appkit

I like to implement my own column resizing scheme in an `NSTableView`. I got this mostly working, but struggle with the dynamic appearance of the vertical scrollbar.

Imagine I want to have a table with two columns, in which the first is always occupying 1/3 and the other the remaining 2/3 of the visible space.

I've tried to accomplish this by implementing the `tile` method in a subclass of `NSTableView` as follows:

```
- (void)tile
{
    NSClipView *container = (NSClipView*) self.superview;

    NSSize spacing = self.intercellSpacing;
    CGFloat avail = container.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat cw0 = (int) (avail / 3);
    CGFloat cw1 = avail - cw0;
    self.tableColumns[0].width = cw0 - spacing.width;
    self.tableColumns[1].width = cw1 - spacing.width;

    [super tile];
}
```

I believe I have to invoke `[super tile]` to have the scrollbars get added as necessary.

The problem, however, is that when I resize the window (and thereby also resizing the TableView), the horizontal scrollbar is sometimes part of the clip view and sometimes isn't, leading to flickering.

Here are examples that I get when resizing the window:

Good outcome:

[image: good resize example]

Bad outcome (note the fact that there's a horizontal scrollbar):

[image: bad resize example]

While I keep resizing the window, the table view keep adding and removing the horizontal scrollbar, thus flickering. This is what I want to avoid.

I wonder how the original `tile` function handles this. How would I enable it so that I don't get the flickering, yet have the scrollbars appear as needed?

Comment: Override `-[NSTableView ]sizeLastColumnToFit`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was pretty easy:

I should have mentioned that I had set the tableview's `columnAutoresizingStyle` to `NSTableViewNoColumnAutoresizing` - because I wanted to manage my own resizing, hence I assumed I'd have to turn Appkit's processing off.

But no - I should set it to `NSTableViewLastColumnOnlyAutoresizingStyle`, and then it works as intended.

I also moved `[super tile];` to the top of the function.